# pwm half bridge inverter- split capacitor voltage alternating

Tags: capacitor, pwm, inverter, load, gate-driving

In the half bridge inverter shown below, when driven by a PWM signal, the voltage Va (the voltage in-between the two capacitors C1 and C3) is a sine wave. I was expecting it to be a constant voltage at a value half of the rail voltage.

[image]

[image]
The second graph is the graphs the pwm is formed from and ho is the pwm signal driving the high side mosfet

Can anyone explain why the voltage here follows the sine wave of the pwm in terms of the switching and voltage and current in the circuit?

Comment: I don't see any signal in your plot that looks like a PWM - we'll need a legend.

Comment: The graphs look like they are from a simulation. If so, show us the actual simulation circuit and give the nodes meaningful names.

Comment: I have updated the images, so the graphs now show the pwm signal for the high side mosfet (ho) - lo will be the opposite of this. The circuit shown is the actual LTSpice circuit that the simulation results are from

Comment: I believe the sloped nature of the ho and vs signals are due to the inductive load